# Is it a bad question, asking about clarification about the circumstances a specific exception occurs?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have asked a [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ywbn.jpg) about the circumstances an exception can occur, because I found no documentation about it. Now it is downvoted twice.

I think it is not broad or primarly opinion based, because there could only be one exact answer (which ofcourse should be documented by the framework):

- scenario 1
- scenario 2
- scenario 3

Am I wrong? Is this kind of question unwanted?

Comment: You're asking for a list of all potentially malicious input. Now, I don't know much about c#, but that seems like an extremely broad question to me. A question like "How can I reliably handle all cases of RequestValidationError?" might be more on-topic.

Comment: You changed the title, but you didn't change the question itself. The question is still asking for a list.

Comment: An exhaustive list of every possible detectable malicious input is *most certainly* Too Broad.  What makes you think that that's *not* too broad?

Comment: @Servy I thought more about 2-3 scenarios, not an exhaustive list. Since I have ever seen only one case, I thought it is not an infinite list.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt You *specifically* said that you need to know about *every* case, not just some of them.  Not that that really makes much of a difference.